# datatables - change button style

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

is there any way to change button style (colvis, copy, print, excel) in angularjs datatables.

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withButtons([
    'colvis',
    'copy',
    'print',
    'excel'
]);
```

Only way I can do this is directly in source code, but this is not good way. 
here is solution with jquery, but this doesn't have any effect in DOM

```
$('#myTable').DataTable( {
buttons: {
    buttons: [
        { extend: 'copy', className: 'copyButton' },
        { extend: 'excel', className: 'excelButton' }
    ]
}
} );
```

css

```
.copyButton {
background-color: red
}
.excelButton{
background-color: red
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply replace a button identifier with a literal and add `className` :

```js
.withButtons([
   'colvis', 
   { extend: 'copy', className: 'copyButton' },
   'print',
   { extend: 'excel', className: 'excelButton' }
]);
```

This works for a "clean" setup, but you are probably including all default stylesheets there is.

DataTables use by default an `<a>` tag and style it to look like a button through a `.dt-button` class which have a lot of pseudo class styling for `:hover` and so on. This makes it complicated to change for example the background, you'll need additional hackish CSS.

Also, DataTables itself already injects unique classes for each button type like `.buttons-excel` which you could take benefit of.

I will suggest you completely reset the default behaviour through the [`dom`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/buttons.dom) option:

```js
.withButtons({
   dom: {
     button: {
       tag: 'button',
       className: ''
     }
   },
   buttons: [
     'colvis', 
     'copy',
     'print',
     'excel'
   ]
})
```

Now you can style for example `.buttons-excel` nicely from scratch :

```css
.buttons-excel {    
  background-color: red;
  color: white; 
  border: 1px outset;
}
.buttons-excel:hover {
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the bootstrap 4 taste of DataTables the buttons automatically have class btn-secondary.
Using the dom option you lose the bootstrap design altogether.
You can however add classes like so:

```
myTable = $('#myTableId').DataTable({
    buttons: [
      { extend: 'colvis', className: 'btn-outline-secondary' },
      { extend: 'excel', className: 'btn-outline-secondary' }
]});
```

But for me this didn't change the button design because the btn-secondary was still there. So I removed it manually afterwords.

```
  setTimeout(function () {
    $oTable.buttons().container().addClass('ml-2').appendTo('#myTableId_length'); //attach buttons to table length choser
    $oTable.buttons().container().find('.btn').removeClass('btn-secondary'); //remove class btn secondary
  }, 500);
```

This is wrapped in a time-out to make sure, everything has been rendered before.